# php execute on specific host

Tags: php, filesystems, shared

I'm writing a shell script to be executed by php page. The page has to be on one server while the script runs on another. Both machines are on a shared file system. How do I specify the host name with the php execute command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use UNIX sockets, ssh, or some other way to connect to the other machine in order to execute it on that machine.  [PECL provides an ssh2 facility to do this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-exec.php).

```
$connection = ssh2_connect('shell.example.com', 22);
ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'username', 'password');
$stream = ssh2_exec($connection, '/usr/local/bin/php -i');
```

Comment: I see, thanks. So if I connect with a given set of credentials, am I logged in in that set's home directory? I.e. if I want to execute something, are all paths relative to username's ~?

Comment: By most SSH defaults, yes you will land in their home directory.

Comment: Thank you so much. Testing now.

Comment: An easy way to get into the user's home directory would be to

$connection = ssh2_connect('shell.example.com', 22);
ssh2_auth_password($connection, $username, 'password');
$stream = ssh2_exec($connection, 'cd /home/' . $username . ';/usr/local/bin/php -i');